# Crystal's rpt published to the wrong folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 in Visual Studio 2010. In my project I have created a 'Crystal' folder containing crystal reports .rpt files. I have set the 'build action' of each .rpt files to 'Content', hoping that these .rpt files will be copied to the target folder when I 'publish'.

Those .rpt files were copied to a 'Crystal' folder indeed, but there was a duplicate 'Crystal' folder below the 'bin' folder.

How can I make the 'Crystal' folder not appear inside the 'bin' folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Copy to Output Directory` option to `Do not copy` for this file.